# trigonometry proof. $\csc(\theta) -\sin(\theta)=\cot(\theta)\cos(\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry

I tried to prove the following equality:

> $\csc(\theta) -\sin(\theta)=\cot(\theta)\cos(\theta)$

Answer (score 2):

$$\csc \theta-\sin\theta=\frac1{\sin \theta}-\sin\theta=\frac{1-\sin^2\theta}{\sin\theta}=\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin\theta}=\cot\theta\cos\theta$$

In general, this is $\ne\cot\theta\sin\theta$.

Comment: question updated. sorry for the confusion .